# Is there a bzrlib function that will (given a repository to look in) output a revision's parents?

Tags: python, linux, repository, bazaar

I am new to Python and Linux and I have been tasked with a project that will utilize the bzrlib toolbox written in python.

The task is as follows. "Create a Python function which accepts the file system path to a local Bazaar (bzr) project and returns the revision and branch of the project's baseline.  Use a driver to demonstrate function objectives"

So basically if I wanted to know the last known merged revision off of the project's baseline I would call the function on the linux command line and then enter the Directory where the repository is located and Revision number from the baseline that I want to check.

Here are some examples of what the input and output may look like:

INPUT: /home/example-directory
INPUT: 134

OUTPUT: 133

INPUT: /home/example-directory
INPUT: 176

OUTPUT: 170.4.5

I have been reading through the bzrlib API to try and find what I am looking for but so far no luck. If anybody has an idea of how I might do this I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Branch.open](https://people.canonical.com/~mwh/bzrlibapi/bzrlib.branch.Branch.html#open) method to open a branch from a path.

The `.repository` attribute of the branch can be used to access its repository.

There are three relevant functions that you'd want to use:

- [Branch.dotted_revno_to_revision_id](https://people.canonical.com/~mwh/bzrlibapi/bzrlib.branch.Branch.html#dotted_revno_to_revision_id) to convert the revision number to a revision id.
- [Repository.get_revision](https://people.canonical.com/~mwh/bzrlibapi/bzrlib.repository.Repository.html#get_revision) to retrieve the metadata for the revision. The "parent_ids" attribute of the metadata will have the parent ids.
- [Branch.revision_id_to_dotted_revno](https://people.canonical.com/~mwh/bzrlibapi/bzrlib.branch.Branch.html#revision_id_to_dotted_revno) to convert the revision ids back to dotted revision numbers

Comment: However, I cannot seem to get the repository.Repository.get_revision to work. I keep getting the (TypeError: unbound method get_revision() must be called with Repository instance as first argument (got str instance instead))

Comment: If you would like me to show you my script I will edit my initial post to include it as well as the error message.

Comment: You need to call .get_revision() on a repository instance, not on the the Repository object itself.

Comment: I used b = Branch.open (d1)

c = b.dotted_revno_to_revision_id((r1,), _cache_reverse=False)

parent_ids = b.repository.get_revision(c).parent_ids

print parent_ids 
That seemed to work!